# How do I handle wildcard subdomains in Dancer routes?

Tags: perl, subdomain, dancer

I'm writing a web app with the Dancer framework and I'd like to offer each user a subdomain, like wordpress.com does.

How can I specify my Dancer routes to take account of the domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how https://github.com/sukria/ThisShit is implemented

Comment: Ah, I need to get the host from the request inside the route:

`get '/' => sub {`
`my $host = request->host;`
`$host =~ s/\.example\.com.*$//;`
`# $host now contains the subdomain`